# HTML5: Adding an image as a canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, 2d-games

Based off [this](https://codepen.io/loktar00/pen/JEdqD) HTML5/JS game tutorial, I'm trying to change the "player" from just a simple color to an image.

How do I add an image to a canvas element?

The code that I'm trying to edit is this part right here:

```js
player.x += player.velX;
player.y += player.velY;

ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: Try and refer this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_createpattern

Comment: You probably want to use [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

Answer (score 0):

```
player.x += player.velX;
player.y += player.velY;

var img = new Image();
img.src = "linkToYourImage.jpg";
//Can be any extension (png, etc.)

ctx.drawImage(img, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

See more options here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: You will need a onload handler for the image since the image is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: True, but I don't know when or where AaronG will load his source image, so I left it omitted.